# How to hide projects in "my timesheet" for users not assigned to the project in openerp 7.0?

Tags: python, odoo

Currently i have a question regarding the my timesheet function. If i create a project and select the `timesheet/stundenzettel` box, the employees are able to enter their working hours on the specific project using the my `timesheet/"mein stundenzettel"` function. So far so good. Unfortunately every user can book on every project where the `timesheet/stundenzettel` box is checked, regardless if he is a member of the project team or not.

As an example i have some freelancers working and some projects but i do not want them to

```
see all company projects
be able to book their working time on wrong projects
```

Is there a way to only show projects where the user is assigned to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the access control list for the timesheet model. You can do that in the Settings >> Technical >> Security >> Access Control List.

In the ACL you can define the rules for accessing the different models. If you need to see how it works, you can check ACLs defined by the sales module.

Comment: @ankita : Was you able to achieve it using ACL?