# How to limit OpenERP “my timesheet” project list?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I’m setting up OpenERP 7.0 using timesheet module, and I want that any user can see only projects assigned to him when he writes his timesheet, using section `My timesheet`.

My problem is that when I log as a user, in `My timesheet` > tab `Summary`, when I and **Add a line** I can see all projects and analytic accounts.  But, If I use `My timesheet` > tab `Details`, I can see only internal projects.

I tried

1. ACL section ([as said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372612/how-to-hide-projects-in-my-timesheet-for-users-not-assigned-to-the-project-in)),
2. group properties,
3. user technical options,

but I failed. The different behaviour of tabs `Summary`and `Details` make me think there is some error in OpenERP code.

How can I managed the project listed for a user?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use domain rules.
You can find a good answer and explanation here: [Understanding OpenERP Domain Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998921/understanding-open-erp-domain-filter)

To configure a domain rule, go to `Settings >> Technical >> Security >> Record Rules`

In other hand, if you want to create your domain rules as you install your module, it might be useful to have them stored in a XML file. 
I'll leave you an example of one I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- ########################### OPINIONS ############################# -->
        <!-- everyone can see issued opinions, but can't edit them -->
        <record id="proc_uc_see_issued_opinions_rule" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">See issued opinions rule</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_opinion"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('state','=','issued')]</field> 
            <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/> <!-- can see -->
            <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/> <!-- can't change it -->
            <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
            <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>             
            <!--<field name="global" eval="True"/>-->
            <field name="global" eval="0" />
            <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0,[ref('processos_uc.group_processos_user')])]"/>        
        </record>

        <!-- consultant can see and edit his opinion requests -->
        <record id="proc_uc_see_own_opinions_rule" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">See own opinions rule</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_opinion"/>
            <field name="domain_force">['|',('consultant_uid','=',user.id),('consultant_uid','=',False)]</field> 
            <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
            <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
            <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
            <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>             
            <field name="global" eval="0" />
            <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0,[ref('processos_uc.group_processos_user')])]"/>        
        </record>
(...)
        <!-- managers can do anything on opipions! -->
        <record id="proc_uc_managers_can_do_anything_opinions_rule" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Managers can do anything on opinions rule</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_opinion"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field> 
            <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
            <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
            <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
            <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>             
            <field name="global" eval="0" />
            <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0,[ref('processos_uc.group_processos_manager')])]"/>        
        </record>
     </data>
</openerp>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks, this helps with the syntax in which I ve to write the rules. Unfortunately, I still can’t understand what rules I have to create or change to get the visualization I’m looking for.  I don’t know very well openERP objects and it’s hard to guess the fields.

Comment: Go to `Settings >> Technical >> Database Structure >> Models` and search for the model you are trying to apply your rules (ou may use the searchbox for that, or to list all object - if not already shown - click the _"1-80 of xxx"_ on the top right, under the searchbox, a select "Unlimited")
Identify the name of the field you want to restrict (it propably will be `user_id`, and it will for sure be a `many2one` field), once you identified the field, the syntax will be `['|', ('your_field_name','=", user.id), ('your_field_name','=", False)]`

Comment: I’ve tried and tested but i’m totally wrong. I have to find the field for `user associated to a project` or `user following a project`. Please, can you help me finding that one, and writing the rule?

Comment: I don't know that module, so I don't know the model either. So I wont be of any great help from now on. But my guess is that you should look for users associated to the project. Anyway, you can create two rules (or the rules you want to) one for users associated to project a give them read / write perms, and a second for users following a project a give them only read permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can get the project list whichever employee has assigned.

```
def default_project(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    cr.execute('''select project_id from project_team_members where uid=%s and is_active='t' limit 1''',(uid,))
    project_id=cr.fetchone()
    if project_id:
        return project_id and project_id[0] or False 
    return False

_defaults = {
        'project_id':default_project,
        }
```